# how to free up recovery disk in win8.1

Tags: windows-8, partitioning, lenovo-laptop

my laptop(lenovo yoga 11s,win8.1)has more than 15g for healthy recovery partition, and in the mean time I am running low on my c disk. I was wondering if there is a way I could free up some recovery disk space, but disk manager seems fail to do that. thx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get this app:
http://download.cnet.com/EaseUS-Partition-Master-Free-Edition/3000-2248_4-10863346.html?tag=mncol%3Bpop&cdlPid=10982635
or this one:
http://www.partition-tool.com/personal.htm

Then delete the recovery one and merge the new free space into your C:.

Answer (score 0):

Can you see the recovery drive in `My Computer` ?

If so, simply doubleclick the recovery drive. It will ask if you have created recovery media and really want to remove the recovery partition. Ask "Yes" to both these questions. Now a script will run, that removes the recovery partition and adds the space freed up to your system drive (typically `C:\`)

After you've done this. Go into `Control Panel > Programs and features` and remove the "Create Recovery Media" application also, as it is no longer needed.

If this doesn't work, have a look [here](http://www.lionhack.com/2013/12/25/lenovo-yoga-2-pro-partitions/), for a different approach (Warning: the method described in this article can be potentially destructive if you mess something up. *If in doubt, back up first*!)

Answer (score 0):

Same in *Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro*.

Found the answer on **How to delete Healthy (Recovery Partition)** [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/4f1b84ac-b193-40e3-943a-f45d52e23685/cant-delete-extra-healthy-recovery-partitions-and-healthy-efi-system-partition?forum=w8itproinstall):

1. Open a command prompt as adminitrator (<kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> then <kbd>A</kbd>)
2. Run Diskpart by typing`diskpart`
3. In the Diskpart prompt, type in `rescan` to re-scan all partitions, volumes and drives available.
4. Then type in `list disk` and to show all hard disk drive available.
5. Select the disk that contains the partition you want to remove. Normally, with just 1 hard disk, it will be disk 0. So the command will be:
   `select disk 0`
6. Type `list partition` to show all available and created partition in the disk selected.
7. Select the partition that wanted to be deleted by using the following command:`select partition x`
   Where x is the number of the recovery partition to be removed and unlocked its space. Be careful with the number of this partition, as wrong number may get data wipes off.
8. Finally, type in `delete partition override`.

If you do not use the `override` option on a **Healthy (Recovery Partition)**, you will get the following error:

> Virtual Disk Service error:
>
> Cannot delete a protected partition without the force protected parameter set.